# ng build --prod is failing on Terser

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I am running ng build --prod on angular 7 application (includes vs C# app on the BE).
I am getting an error

```
ERROR in scripts.db02b1660e4ae815041b.js from Terser
Unexpected token: keyword (var) [scripts.db02b1660e4ae815041b.js:5,8]
```

It looks like that the problem not with the plugin itself but like it can't resolve something.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to search for keyword var in your code. I think angular wouldnt allow using var keyword